# Code branched/shared on VSTS and Local TFS

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, tfvc

TFS is used in house. Would like to use VSTS to collaborate with an external resource.

Logically, I would like to create a branch from the in-house TFS to a VSTS repository, but TFS and VSTS can't be mapped to the same file system location. I have seen ways to do one-time migrations from one system to the other, but I can't find any guidance about living in both systems at the same time.

How do I manage the same code in both TFS and VSTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you make the switch to Git, which can be hosted inside TFS and VSTS. Combined with CI builds that also sync code between repositories can make this a very effective setup. Git is designed to handle distributed development over multiple repositories and is ideally suited for scenario's such as yours.

Your developers can also push/pull between onprem and VSTS quite easily from their local development machine.

This functionality isn't available on TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control), but VSTS and recent versions of TFS can now import your main branch with history into Git in a quick one-time process. From there it's not a lot of work (relatively) to make the technical switch. My personal trick would be to import your main branch into Git on the TFS end and then use [the mirror guidance to clone your repo to VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/move-git-repos-between-team-projects) without having to import the Onprem server into VSTS.

The hard bit of the transition is training your people and getting them comfortable with the changed tools and workflow.